# Magento 2.x: add column to sales order history page (FO)

Tags: magento2, addition, account

How we can add column to Sales order history content into customer account.

What are methods for add a column to `sales_order_history page` without editing `view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to touch ***view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml*** template file to add aditional column into customer sales order history page.

copy layout ***view/frontend/layout/sales_order_history.xml*** to your theme and add addtional column header to ***sales.order.history.extra.column.header*** block and render column data using ***sales.order.history.extra.container*** block.

You have all set now.

Comment: I would have added the code as bellow in my layout **view/frontend/layout/sales_order_history.xml** but no result showing:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53534855/magento-2-x-add-column-to-sales-order-history-page-fo/53670341#53670341

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- This will add additional column header to order list -->
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history.extra.column.header">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="your.additional.column.header" template="Namespace_Module::columnheader.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>

        <!-- You can access current order using $this->getOrder() inside the template ">
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history.extra.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="your.additional.column.data" template="Namespace_Module::columndata.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: but replace "extra.container" to "sales.order.history.extra.container"

Answer (score 0):

I have an easier and shorter solution(date column in the example):

1- Create in your theme/extension into layout folder-> sales_order_history.xml and copy:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history.extra.container" template="Magento_Sales::order/date/data.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

2- Create the template for the data in templates/date/data.phtml and copy:

```
<?php
/* @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History\Container */
?>
<td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date">
    <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrder()->getCreatedAt()) ?></td>
```